# Import libraries to Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, import, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I tried with no luck for two days import one of these two libraries to implement swipe to dimiss into my ListView.
One of them ir very famous (https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview)

With both of them happened the same thing.
I follow the steps and setup buil.gradle correctly, download the .arr files that is now on my /build folder, no .jar was added into External Libraries folder, I was able to use the classes from the library, compile and run the project on my device but both of cases the list still behave like a ordinary ListView. I already restart the Android Studio because some of answers here said to do that in the cases like that.

I think it is very strange because no error was found and I can use the classes like any other.
Do I have to do any other thing to import the libraries properly? Even when I import with dependencys on build.gradle should I see .jar file in External Libraries or not?

I am using Android Studio 4.3 with gradle 1.10 wich people said that has less bugs from import libraries. Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'de.timroes.android:EnhancedListView:0.2.0@aar'
    compile files('libs/EnhancedListView-0.2.0.aar')
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.mobeta.android.dslv:drag-sort-listview:0.6.1'

}
```

Comment: if you can import and there is no problem in compilation that nothing to do with dependencies. It might be a problem in the implementation. Check it once more.

Comment: I check. I create a simple project and copy a simple demo but it doesnt work. Did you know If in this case I should see a .jar in libs folder or it is just the .aar?

Comment: It will be aar because library has some resources in it. check this once , inside you module/build/exploded-bundles is the directory available there for your library with .aar and resources are copied properly inside it? Also i did not get why you use `EnhancedListView-0.2.0.aar` twice in dependencies ?

Comment: Yes. It is exactaly how it was on my folder. 
I put the second line because I tought it may be a problem with the lib folder, but even without this line I get the same result. I can declare a EnhancedListView or a DragDropListView without problem, but the list behave like a simple ListView. Another thing that I found strange is the fact that I cant preview the layout of this customized lists ( but it doesnt show any rendering problems) like the ListView ( with Item1,Item2, Item3, etc). When you import a library like that it should preview the layout?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **EnhancedListView** but I also wasn't able to use the library with just `compile 'de.timroes.android:EnhancedListView:0.2.0@aar'` in the build.gradle even though the [docs](https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView/wiki) says so.

Instead, I had to do exactly what the demo project does, which is importing the module to the project and configuring the files.

setting.gradle:

```
include ':EnhancedListView'
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':EnhancedListView')
}
```

This is not a real answer but should get you started.

Comment: Can you say if I am doing it right?
Erase the line compile 'de.timroes.android:EnhancedListView:0.2.0@aar', create a new module, copy the folder EnhancedListView to this module and add the lines you put in the answer? By the way, when you can`t use the library was you able to use classes from it and run the code? 
I was looking for someone with the same problem but cant find any question about it here.

Comment: I had the same problem as you. It's like the aar file is corrupted or something. I was able to use just some classes but not all of them. There is nothing wrong in your aproach. I don't know why it doesn't work but if you do exactly what the demo project does, it works.

Comment: I haave this problem with all the libraries that I tried to import, so I think it is a problem of AS. Do you have this trouble with another libraries?